# Surpress Call/Response Logs Office.js

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to turn off these logs? It's pretty much impossible to `console.log` almost anything because the console is filled with these:

```
Agave.HostCall.IssueCall
Agave.HostCall.ReceiveResponse
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to suppress these messages. However, your question did spark the discussion on why these are showing up to begin with, and we are looking at removing them the next time that Office.js is updated.

Thanks for bringing it up to our attention!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: With the latest update of office.js I don't get this in the log anymore :)

Comment: With the hosted office.js and a sample Word app it just started occuring again.

Comment: @Rvanlaak, could you post an issue on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues describing where/how you're seeing this?